# trap INT doesn't work when executing a virtualenv or pip in a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, virtualenv

I have a deb package with a post_install script which should create a python virtual environment and install requirements on it. the problem is when the user presses `ctrl+c`, `virtualenv` or `pip` command interrupts, prints an error message and the next command executes instead of running trap handler.

I tried to run `virtualenv` in background get its PID and wait for it to execute but it didn't work.
something like:

```sh
function sig_int(){
   echo "exiting..."
   kill -SIGINT $PID
   exit 255
}

virtualenv -p python3 <somewhere> &
PID=$!
trap sig_int INT
wait $PID
```

the script is sth like this:

```sh
function sig_int(){
   echo "exiting..."
   # do some cleanup
   exit 255
}

trap sig_int INT

virtualenv -p python3 <somewhere>
. <somewhere>/bin/activate

pip3 install req1
pip3 install req2

read -p "> Please enter username: " user
read -s -p "> Please enter password: " pass
...
```

the script never runs the trap function by pressing `ctrl+c`. when pip3 install or virtualenv are running pressing `ctrl+c` just interrupts pip3 or virtualenv and continues to execute when pressing `ctrl+c` in reading block script just exits.

Comment: The correct way to obtain administrator configuration preferences for package installation is through Debconf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, this is an issue due to spawned background jobs, which you will need to kill all as well. I solved a similar issue by doing the following, but be aware, that this kills also parental processes.

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
trap 'die' INT TERM
trap 'kill -PIPE 0' EXIT

die() {
    echo "error: $*" >&2
    exit 255
}

<cmd> || die '<cmd> failed'
```